# Android window leak error in fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, asynchronous, fragment, progressdialog

Hi I am working with android Fragments. I created a progress dialogue while loading json from the server using asynchronous task .But it works fine and some times cause window leak error. I created the dialogue in onPreExcecute method and load contents in doingbackground and dismiss my dialogue in onpost excecute method.I think this is the right way .But why did I cause this window leak error sometimes ?? This is my code .Please help me Thanks in advance :)

```
public class PendingWork extends Fragment {

ListView lv;
public ProgressDialog pDialog;
EditText inputSearch;
// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

static ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> pendingList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

SharedPreferences app_pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor appedt;
static JSONArray jArray2 = null;

String picture, complaint_id[],complaint_type[],engine_model[],customer_id[],customer_name[],customer_address[],description[],date[];

// Inbox JSON url
  final String PENDING_URL = "myURl";

// ALL JSON node names

private static final String TAG_ID = "cmp_id";
private static final String TAG_TYPE = "cmp_type";
private static final String TAG_ENGINE = "engine";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "cust_name";
private static final String TAG_DATE = "date";
private static final String TAG_DESC = "descriptn";
private String TAG_PIC;

int textlength=0;

//Date strDate;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pending_list, container, false);
     inputSearch = (EditText)rootView. findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        // Hashmap for ListView

        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        pendingList.clear();

        // Loading pending list in Background Thread
        new Loadpending().execute();


        lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    //  lv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);

        app_pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF",getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
        appedt=app_pref.edit();

 /*--------------------------------------------------listview click listener------------------------------------------------*/

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> apt, View v, int pos,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                  appedt.putString("complt_id", complaint_id[pos]);
                //  appedt.putString("imei", IMEI_no);
                  appedt.commit();

                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        b.putString("type", complaint_type[pos]);
                        b.putString("id", complaint_id[pos]);
                        b.putString("date", date[pos]);
                        b.putString("engine", engine_model[pos]);
                        b.putString("cus_name", customer_name[pos]);
                        b.putString("cus_id", customer_id[pos]);
                        b.putString("cus_addr", customer_address[pos]);
                        b.putString("desc", description[pos]);
                        b.putString("flag", "1");


                Intent in=new Intent(getActivity(),Pend_Details.class);
                in.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(in);

            }

        });


       inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
              // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,
            int start, int count, int after)
            {
            // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
            }
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,
            int start, int before, int count)
            {
            textlength = inputSearch.getText().length();
            pendingList.clear();

            for (int j = 0; j < jArray2.length(); j++)
            {
            try {
                if (textlength <= jArray2.getJSONObject(j).length())
                {
                    if(inputSearch.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String)((CharSequence) jArray2.getJSONObject(j).getString("complnt_type")).subSequence(0,textlength)) || 
                            inputSearch.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String)((CharSequence) jArray2.getJSONObject(j).getString("name")).subSequence(0,textlength)) )
                                {
                                    SetList(j);

                                }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
     }

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    getActivity(), pendingList,
                    R.layout.fragment_pending_list_item2, new String[] { TAG_TYPE, TAG_NAME, TAG_DATE},
                    new int[] { R.id.title,R.id.name, R.id.location});
            // updating listview
            lv.setAdapter(adapter); 
        }
        });

    return rootView;
}
class Loadpending extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pendingList.clear();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting Inbox JSON
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        app_pref=getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF", 0);
        String  tech_id = app_pref.getString("username", "");

        jArray2 = jsonParser.ParseJson(PENDING_URL, "GET",tech_id);

    //Log.w("Lengh",""+jArray2.length());

    complaint_id = new String[jArray2.length()];
    complaint_type = new String[jArray2.length()];
    engine_model = new String[jArray2.length()];
    customer_id = new String[jArray2.length()];
    customer_name = new String[jArray2.length()];
    customer_address = new String[jArray2.length()];
    description = new String[jArray2.length()];
    date = new String[jArray2.length()];

    pendingList.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < jArray2.length(); i++) {

        SetList(i);                 
        }

    return null;
}

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        getActivity(), pendingList,
                        R.layout.fragment_pending_list_item2, new String[] { TAG_TYPE, TAG_NAME, TAG_DATE},
                        new int[] { R.id.title,R.id.name, R.id.location });
                // updating listview
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

      }

  }


  }
```

Comment: Check your doInBackground method. it create exception or something before complete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this check before show your ProgressDialogue

```
if(!isCancelled())
{               
dialog.show();  
}
```